# Applications of small object argument outside model categories.

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

Are there applications of the small object argument outside of its original application of constructing the factorisation for a model category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the small object argument to solve the orthogonal subcategory problem. Of course, that is simply because this is a special case of the construction of (functorial) orthogonal factorisation systems, which is in turn a special case of the construction of (functorial) weak factorisation systems.

Comment: Do you have a reference  where I can read about it?

Comment: Not especially. It's quite easy once you understand the problem.